# Redirect to specific tab in view

Tags: component, joomla-3.4, view, bootstrap

I'm working on a Joomla component and need help in redirecting to specific tab.

I have created multiple tabs in my view using bootstrap (eg: JHtml::_('bootstrap.startTabSet', 'myTab', array('active' => 'tab1')). I can set the default active tab by passing 'active' => 'tabname'. However, I want to control this dynamically after any actions performed on the view in any specific tab.

For example, if the user clicks the save button while in Tab3, I want to return to Tab3 after the save action completes. Currently it goes back to tab1 as I set that as default.

Can anyone help me how to identify the current tab and redirect to the same tab after any action by the user?

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the tab where you are in the link.

I did it once like this:

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input; 
$tab    = $jinput->getString('tab', 'info');

$tabinfo  = false;
$tabphoto = false;
$tabmap   = false;

if ($tab == 'photos')
{
    $tabphoto = true;
} 
elseif ($tab == 'map') 
{
    $tabmap = true;
}
else
{
    $tabinfo = true;
}
```

**The HTML:**

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">

    <li class="<?php echo ($tabinfo)?'active':''?>">
        <a href="#info" data-toggle="tab">
            <?php echo JText::_('WBS_COMPANY_INFO');?>
        </a>
    </li>

    <li class="<?php echo ($tabphoto)?'active':''?>">
        <a href="#photos" data-toggle="tab">
            <?php echo JText::_('WBS_COMPANY_PHOTOS');?>
        </a>
    </li>

    <li class="<?php echo ($tabmap)?'active':''?>">
        <a href="#map" data-toggle="tab">
            <?php echo JText::_('WBS_COMPANY_MAP');?>
        </a>
    </li>

</ul>

<div class="tab-content">

     <div id="info" class="tab-pane <?php echo ($tabinfo)?'active':''?>">
     </div>

     <div id="photos" class="tab-pane <?php echo ($tabphoto)?'active':''?>">
     </div>

     <div id="map" class="tab-pane <?php echo ($tabmap)?'active':''?>">
     </div>

</div>
```

Comment: `JRequest` is deprecated! This also doesn't utilise `JHtml`...it's hardcoded

Comment: I corrected the jrequest, I hope it helps even is not JHtml